# Use two push-es in update command

Tags: mongodb

Well the answer is probably no but I am curious to ask.

I have a Document which has two level of arrays in it:

```
{ '_id : '...' , events : [ urls : [], social_id : [] ], 'other_data' : '...' }
```

The code below works. What is does is update on a specific event the url array and adds to that set the `event['event_url']` value (python).

```
db.col.update(
            {   'f_id'     :      venue['id'],
                "events.title" :  find_dict["events.title"]   },
            { '$addToSet': { 'events.$.urls':  event['event_url']}   }
    )
```

However in the same event I want to add a social id if not exists.

```
db.col.update(
            {   'f_id'     :      venue['id'],
                "events.title" :  find_dict["events.title"]   },
            { '$addToSet': { 'events.$.social_id':  event['social_id']}   }
    )
```

I was wandering if it's possible to merge the above commands into one and not run the update twice. I have not found anything in the documentation but I guess it's worth asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the two updates into a single operation by including both fields in the `$addToSet` object:

```js
db.col.update(
    { 'f_id': venue['id'], "events.title": find_dict["events.title"] },
    { '$addToSet': { 
        'events.$.urls.': event['event_url'],
        'events.$.social_id.':  event['social_id']
    }}
)
```